# Is it legal to drop share price through false statements?

Tags: shares, market-manipulation

Let's say the CEO of a multinational public company goes to an interview and says "we have hard times coming". Then, the share price drops. Later, the fiscal assets and report of the company is revealed. This reveals that the company is doing great and share price again rises. During this period the CEO manages to buy a large portion of stock at the expense of the trust of shareholders. Is this legal?

Comment: If you mean in the US, sure, it's illegal.  They have thought of that.

Comment: This would be fraud, and could land the CEO in prison.

Comment: You are probably better off asking this on the [law.se] site.

Comment: Then migrate this, I would also be interested to know under which law will this procecution be done?What the CEO says he was really telling truth then?

Comment: It's not illegal to _say_ it; it's illegal to _make money_ from it. The CEO cannot trade shares wihile having insider knowledge.

Comment: I do not know much about trading but can you tell what you meant by "CEO cannot trade while having insider knowledge" . What if he helps someone else through this process and then take some states from that person?

Comment: I was wondering how many such frauds take place.

Comment: Insider trading is illegal, most country have enough safeguards